# HTML5 Trouble with positioning text within elements

Tags: css, html

I'm having trouble with the text within the button  in particular. Whenever I try to apply padding to the top or bottom of the button so the text is centered, bu all it does is move the whole button. I suspect it has a lot to do with my lack of understanding with positioning and display.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>WhiteGrid</title>
    <link type="text.css" rel="stylesheet" href= "stylesheet.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div id="header"><img src="title.png"></div>
        <div id="navbar">
            <div class="button"><p>Home</p></div>
            <div class="button"><p>Gallery</p></div>
            <div class="button"><p>About</p></div>
            <div class="button"><p>Settings</p></div>

        </div>
        <div id="body"></div>
        <div id="footer"><p>Copyright&copy 2015 Hayden Shaw. All rights reserved.</p></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: #C6C1C9;
}

#header {
    display: block;
    background-color: #856799;
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
#header > img {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}

#navbar {
    display: block;
    background-color: rgba(73,71,74,0.7);
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
#body {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    min-height:500px;
}
#footer {
    padding-top:24px;
    display: block;
    background-color: #7D7285;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
#footer > p {
    position: relative;
    text-shadow: 0px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    color: #A3A3A3;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 10px;
    text-align: center;

}
.button{
    margin:0px;
    text-shadow: 0px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    font-family: Verdana;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 40px;
    width: 80px;
    background-color: rgba(73,71,74,0);
}
.button:hover{
    background-color: #353336;
    color: #856799;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Don't apply padding to the button but to the paragraph you have the text in. If you are having trouble laying out the text, I would suggest using an image of the text which would be easier.

It seems like you are trying to create a menu bar. I wouldn't do it using divs. Using a table or list is much easier.

```
<table>
        <tr>
    <td>Home</td>
    </tr>
        </table>

    <ul>
    <li>Home</li>
</ul>
```

This will be much easier to style.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use positioning for this. And you shouldn't be using `div`'s to create buttons either, for a number of reasons.

The best thing you could do is use the `<button />` element, or use an [anchor tag](http://jsfiddle.net/9ds6f1xu/) instead:

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="paddedButton khaki noUnderline">Button</a>
```

CSS:

```
.paddedButton
{
    padding: 10px;
}

.khaki
{
    background-color: khaki;
}

.noUnderline
{
    text-decoration: none;
}

.noUnderline:hover
{
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```